# Angle between x-axis and major axis of ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

The MathWorld resource [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html) gives a formula for the counter-clockwise angle $\phi$ between the x-axis and the major-axis of an ellipse $a x^2 +2bxy + cy^2 + 2dx + 2fy + g = 0$ as

[image]

But what do I do when $a=c$? For example the ellipse below is rotated by $\pi/4$ but $a$ and $c$ are equal so are undefined in the above equation. Does this formula need a slight tweak (with a "$\leq$" symbol)?

[image]

Comment: All angle calculations _should_ always use the `atan2()` operator.

Comment: @ja72 I wouldn't understand how to implement that, or how it should be implemented here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the answer as

$$ \phi = \frac{1}{2} {\rm atan}\left(\frac{2 b}{a-c}\right) = \mbox{  0.5*atan2(2b, a-c) } $$

You will also find that

$$\begin{align} 
  \cos (2 \phi) &= \frac{a-c}{\sqrt{(a-c)^2+4 b^2}} \\
  \sin (2 \phi) &= \frac{2 b}{\sqrt{(a-c)^2+4 b^2}} 
\end{align}$$

Comment: ahh I get it, thanks.

Comment: just for certainty, I would implement this is Mathematica's notation (see link below, second equation top of page in yellow) as (1/2)ArcTan[a-c,2b], yes?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html

Comment: Yes, $\Delta x = a-c$ and $\Delta y = 2 b$. That's why I added the `sin` and `cos` expansions. Mathematica has `ArcTan[Δx,Δy]` and most other places have `atan2(Δy, Δx)`. It is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=c$, and $b=0$, then the ellipse is actually a circle, so it doesn't have a major axis. This being the case, it's not too surprising that the formulae don't work. The MathWorld page should have mentioned this; it's not entirely obvious.

For details, see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant_classification).

Comment: I don't think this is true. In the question above I plotted an ellipse with $a=c=5/32$ and it does not seem to be an ellipse

Comment: I think it is true. Your example doesn't have $b=0$

Comment: Yes I think it is true now, I think you edited it. Before there wasn't the b=0 qualifier. No matter :)